# Don't understand cause of RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to use a map generator I made a few months ago. I remember it worked, I even showed it to some people, but now, it just doesn't work. I havent changed the python version, so this feels quite weird.

When I try to execute the code, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError:
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

I have made some research, and the only thing I find is people saying "add the line `freeze_support()` and it'll work", and it usually does, but it isn't working for me. I've tried `torch.multiprocessing.freeze_support()`, `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` and `freeze_support()`, but it gives the exact same error.

Here is my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import signal
import sys
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Value, Array
from threading import Thread
import pygame as pg

vec = pg.math.Vector2

manager = Manager()

SETTINGS = manager.dict()

start_settings = Value('i', 0)
in_settings = Value('i', 0)
quit_settings = Value('i', 0)
reset_settings = Value('i', 0)
generation_finished = Value('i', 0)
generation_started = Value('i', 0)
chunks_generated = Value('i', 0)
apply_settings = Value('i', 0)


SETTINGS["oct"] = 1
SETTINGS["scl"] = 250
SETTINGS["sea"] = 60
SETTINGS["lac"] = 2
SETTINGS["seed"] = 0
SETTINGS["wdh"] = 600
SETTINGS["hgt"] = 600
SETTINGS["offset"] = [0, 0]
SETTINGS["mwd"] = 600
SETTINGS["mhg"] = 600
SETTINGS["zoom"] = 0
SETTINGS["zoom_slider"] = 0
SETTINGS["noise"] = 2

SHARED_MAP = manager.dict()


def remap(OldValue, OldMin, OldMax, NewMin, NewMax):
    OldRange = (float(OldMax) - float(OldMin))
    NewRange = (float(NewMax) - float(NewMin))
    NewValue = (((float(OldValue) - float(OldMin)) * NewRange) / OldRange) + float(NewMin)
    return NewValue


def create_noise(iterations, x, y, scale, lacunarity, low, high, ngen):
    maxAmp = 0
    amp = 1
    persistence = 0.5
    freq = scale
    noise = 0

    for i in range(iterations):
        noise = noise + ngen.noise2d(x/freq, y/freq) * amp
        maxAmp = maxAmp + amp
        amp = amp * persistence
        freq = freq / lacunarity

    noise = noise / maxAmp

    noise = noise * (high - low) / 2 + (high + low) / 2

    return int(high-noise)


def draw_colored(octv, scale, sea, width, height, lac, pos, seed, noise, offset):

    from noise import pnoise2, snoise2
    from opensimplex import OpenSimplex
    import numpy as np

    generation_started.value = 1
    xoffset = offset[0] + pos[0]
    yoffset = offset[1] + pos[1]
    world = np.full((height, width, 3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
    normal_world = world.copy()
    # Color all pixels
    for x in range(width):
        # print(x)
        for y in range(height):
            if noise == 2:
                n = remap(snoise2((x+xoffset)/scale, (y+yoffset)/scale,
                                  octaves=octv, base=seed, lacunarity=lac), -1, 1, 0, 100)
            elif noise == 1:
                n = remap(pnoise2((x+xoffset)/scale, (y+yoffset)/scale,
                                  octaves=octv, base=seed, lacunarity=lac), -1, 1, 0, 100)
            elif noise == 0:
                ngen = OpenSimplex(seed)
                n = create_noise(octv, x+xoffset, y+yoffset, scale, lac, 0, 100, ngen)

            color_dist = int((100-sea)/(octv+2))

            if n >= sea:
                r = range(sea, 100, color_dist)
                hmap = []
                cmap = []
                for i in r:
                    hmap.append(i)
                    cmap.append(remap(i, sea, 100, 150, 255))

                d = 255-max(cmap)

                for i, h in enumerate(hmap):
                    if n >= h:
                        normal_world[y][x][0] = cmap[i]/6
                        normal_world[y][x][1] = cmap[i] + d
                        normal_world[y][x][2] = cmap[i]/2

                        world[y][x][0] = cmap[i]/2
                        world[y][x][1] = cmap[i]
                        world[y][x][2] = cmap[i]/3

            else:
                r = range(0, sea, color_dist*2+1)
                hmap = []
                cmap = []
                for i in r:
                    hmap.append(i)
                    cmap.append(remap(i, 0, sea, 50, 150))

                for i, h in enumerate(hmap):
                    if n >= h:
                        normal_world[y][x][0] = 0
                        normal_world[y][x][1] = 0
                        normal_world[y][x][2] = cmap[i]

                        world[y][x][0] = cmap[i]
                        world[y][x][1] = 0
                        world[y][x][2] = 0

    SHARED_MAP[tuple(pos)] = normal_world
    generation_started.value = 0
    generation_finished.value = 1
    chunks_generated.value += 1


def sw():

    import pygame as pg
    from pgui import Slider, Entry, Button, CheckBox
    import json
    import os

    pg.init()
    pg.display.set_caption("Settings")

    class CustomCheckBox:
        def __init__(self, parent, *, x=0, y=0, size=20):
            self.parent = parent
            self.screen = parent.screen
            self.box = CheckBox(self, x=x, y=y, size=size)

            self.bg_color = (255, 255, 255)
            self.border_width = 3
            self.border_color = (0, 0, 0)
            self.check_color = (0, 200, 0)
            self.cross_width = 5
            self.checked = False
            self.check_style = "fill"
            self.label_side = "top"
            self.label_align = "left"
            self.label_padding = 3

        def update(self):
            self.group = self.parent.noise_options
            if self.box.clicked:
                self.checked = True
                for c in self.group:
                    if c != self:
                        c.checked = False
            else:
                pass
            self.sync_attributes()
            self.box.update()

        def sync_attributes(self):
            # ------- ATTRIBUTES -------
            self.box.bg_color = self.bg_color
            self.box.border_width = self.border_width
            self.box.border_color = self.border_color
            self.box.check_color = self.check_color
            self.box.cross_width = self.cross_width
            self.box.checked = self.checked
            self.box.check_style = self.check_style
            self.box.label_side = self.label_side
            self.box.label_align = self.label_align
            self.box.label_padding = self.label_padding
            # --------------------------

        def move(self, x, y):
            self.box.move(x, y)

        def set_font(self, font):
            self.box.set_font(font)

        def set_font_size(self, size):
            self.box.set_font_size(size)

        def set_font_color(self, color):
            self.box.set_font_color(color)

        def set_size(self, size):
            self.box.set_size(size)

        def set_style(self, style):
            self.box.set_style(style)

        def set_label(self, text):
            self.box.set_label(text)

    class Screen:
        def create(self):

            self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))

            self.load_button = Button(self, text="Load config", func=self.load)
            self.load_button.move(20, 555)
            self.load_button.height = 25
            self.load_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.save_button = Button(self, text="Save config", func=self.save)
            self.save_button.move(145, 555)
            self.save_button.height = 25
            self.save_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.reset_button = Button(self, text="Reset config", func=self.reset)
            self.reset_button.move(270, 555)
            self.reset_button.height = 25
            self.reset_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.opensimplex_option = CustomCheckBox(self, x=20, y=20)
            self.opensimplex_option.check_color = (0, 0, 0)
            self.opensimplex_option.set_font_size(15)
            self.opensimplex_option.set_label("OpenSimplex noise")
            self.opensimplex_option.label_side = "right"
            self.opensimplex_option.label_padding = 5

            self.perlin_noise_option = CustomCheckBox(self, x=20, y=50)
            self.perlin_noise_option.check_color = (0, 0, 0)
            self.perlin_noise_option.set_font_size(15)
            self.perlin_noise_option.set_label("Perlin noise")
            self.perlin_noise_option.label_side = "right"
            self.perlin_noise_option.label_padding = 5

            self.simplex_option = CustomCheckBox(self, x=20, y=80)
            self.simplex_option.check_color = (0, 0, 0)
            self.simplex_option.set_font_size(15)
            self.simplex_option.set_label("Simplex noise")
            self.simplex_option.label_side = "right"
            self.simplex_option.label_padding = 5

            self.settings_file = Entry(self, x=20, y=500, border=1, size=15, width=300)
            self.settings_file.width = 300
            self.settings_file.text = "settings.json"
            self.settings_file.set_label("Settings file:")

            self.noise_options = [
                self.opensimplex_option,
                self.perlin_noise_option,
                self.simplex_option
            ]

            self.noise_options[SETTINGS["noise"]].checked = True

            self.widgets = [
                self.load_button,
                self.save_button,
                self.reset_button,
                self.opensimplex_option,
                self.perlin_noise_option,
                self.simplex_option,
                self.settings_file
            ]

            for w in self.widgets:
                w.border_width = 1

        def load(self):
            filename = self.settings_file.text
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                    settings = json.load(f)

                SETTINGS.update(settings)

                self.apply_settings()
                self.settings_file.set_label("Settings file:")
            else:
                self.settings_file.set_label("Settings file:    No file at " + os.path.abspath(filename))

        def save(self):
            settings = SETTINGS.copy()
            filename = "settings.json"
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(settings, f)

        def apply_settings(self):
            apply_settings.value = 1
            for i in self.noise_options:
                i.checked = False
            self.noise_options[SETTINGS["noise"]].checked = True

        def reset(self):
            reset_settings.value = 1
            SETTINGS["noise"] = 2
            self.noise_options[2].checked = True
            self.noise_options[0].checked = False
            self.noise_options[1].checked = False

        def run(self):
            if start_settings.value:
                self.create()
                start_settings.value = 0
                in_settings.value = 1
            if in_settings.value:
                self.update()
                self.events()
            if quit_settings.value:
                raise SystemExit

        def update(self):
            self.screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            for w in self.widgets:
                w.update()

            noises = [
                self.opensimplex_option.checked,
                self.perlin_noise_option.checked,
                self.simplex_option.checked
            ]

            for i, n in enumerate(noises):
                if noises[i]:
                    SETTINGS["noise"] = i

            pg.display.flip()

        def events(self):
            if in_settings.value:
                for event in pg.event.get():
                    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                        in_settings.value = 0
                        pg.display.quit()
                    elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                            in_settings.value = 0
                            pg.display.quit()

    sc = Screen()
    while True:
        sc.run()


def editor():
    import pygame as pg
    from pgui import Slider, Entry, Button, CheckBox
    import os
    import cv2

    pg.init()

    screen = pg.display.set_mode((1200, 704))
    pg.display.set_caption("Map creator")

    class Editor:
        def __init__(self):
            self.screen = screen
            self.value = 5

            self.oct_slider = Slider(self, max=7)
            self.oct_slider.move(20, 40)
            self.oct_slider.set_length(300)
            self.oct_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.oct_slider.set_width(15)
            self.oct_slider.set_label("Octaves: 1")
            self.oct_slider.set_mark(0)

            self.sea_level_slider = Slider(self)
            self.sea_level_slider.move(20, 80)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_length(300)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_width(15)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_label("Sea level: 60")
            self.sea_level_slider.set_mark(60)

            self.scale_slider = Slider(self, max=599)
            self.scale_slider.move(575, 660)
            self.scale_slider.set_length(585)
            self.scale_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.scale_slider.set_width(15)
            self.scale_slider.set_label("Scale: 100")
            self.scale_slider.set_mark(99)

            self.zoom_slider = Slider(self, max=200, orientation="vertical")
            self.zoom_slider.move(525, 25)
            self.zoom_slider.set_length(585)
            self.zoom_slider.label_align = "center"
            self.zoom_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.zoom_slider.set_label("Zoom: 1")
            self.zoom_slider.set_width(15)
            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(175)
            self.zoom = 1

            self.map_surface = pg.Surface((600, 600))
            self.map_surface.fill(0)
            self.map_rect = self.map_surface.get_rect()
            self.map_rect.topleft = (575, 25)
            self.map = pg.Surface((SETTINGS["wdh"], SETTINGS["hgt"]))
            self.map.fill((100, 100, 100))

            self.width_slider = Slider(self, max=120)
            self.width_slider.move(20, 120)
            self.width_slider.set_length(300)
            self.width_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.width_slider.set_width(15)
            self.width_slider.set_label("Width: 600")
            self.width_slider.set_mark(50)

            self.height_slider = Slider(self, max=120)
            self.height_slider.move(20, 160)
            self.height_slider.set_length(300)
            self.height_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.height_slider.set_width(15)
            self.height_slider.set_label("Height: 600")
            self.height_slider.set_mark(50)

            self.pos_entry = Entry(self, x=20, y=200, border=1, size=15)
            self.pos_entry.text = '0,0'
            self.pos_entry.set_label("X,Y Position:")

            self.lac_slider = Slider(self, max=40)
            self.lac_slider.move(20, 240)
            self.lac_slider.set_length(300)
            self.lac_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.lac_slider.set_width(15)
            self.lac_slider.set_label("Lacunarity: 2")
            self.lac_slider.set_mark(10)

            self.seed_entry = Entry(self, x=20, y=360, border=1, size=15)
            self.seed_entry.text = '0'
            self.seed_entry.set_label("Seed:")

            self.draw_button = Button(self, x=20, y=625, text="Generate", func=self.draw)
            self.draw_button.width = 315

            self.clear_button = Button(self, x=345, y=625, text="Clear", func=self.clear)

            self.settings_button = Button(self, x=20, y=570, text='Settings', func=self.settings)
            self.settings_button.height = 25
            self.settings_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.abort_button = Button(self, x=140, y=570, text='Abort', func=self.abort_generation)
            self.abort_button.height = 25
            self.abort_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.save_button = Button(self, x=260, y=570, text='Save', func=self.save)
            self.save_button.height = 25
            self.save_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.save_name = Entry(self, x=380, y=570)
            self.save_name.text = "image.png"
            self.save_name.set_font_size(15)
            self.save_name.set_label("Save to file:")

            self.widgets = [
                self.oct_slider,
                self.sea_level_slider,
                self.draw_button,
                self.scale_slider,
                self.zoom_slider,
                self.width_slider,
                self.height_slider,
                self.pos_entry,
                self.lac_slider,
                self.seed_entry,
                self.clear_button,
                self.settings_button,
                self.abort_button,
                self.save_button,
                self.save_name
            ]

            self.width_chunks = 4
            self.height_chunks = 4

            for w in self.widgets:
                w.border_width = 1
                if isinstance(w, Slider):
                    w.pointer_border_width = 1

            self.movable_map_rect = pg.Rect((0, 0), (600, 600))
            self.dragging = False
            self.dist = vec(0, 0)

        def settings(self):
            start_settings.value = 1

        def save(self):
            filename = self.save_name.text
            if filename[-4:] != ".png":
                filename += ".png"
            surf = pg.transform.rotate(self.map, 90)
            surf = pg.transform.flip(surf, 0, 1)
            image = []
            for x in range(SETTINGS["mwd"]):
                row = []
                for y in range(SETTINGS["mhg"]):
                    row.append(surf.get_at((x, y)))
                image.append(row)
            image = np.array(image)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            print("saving image")
            cv2.imwrite(filename, image)

        def abort_generation(self):
            if generation_started.value:
                print("Generation aborted")
                for p in self.draw_threads:
                    p.terminate()
                    p.join()
                generation_started.value = 0

        def draw(self):
            SETTINGS["mwd"] = SETTINGS["wdh"]
            SETTINGS["mhg"] = SETTINGS["hgt"]

            SHARED_MAP.clear()
            chunks_generated.value = 0

            self.draw_threads = []

            for x in range(self.width_chunks):
                for y in range(self.height_chunks):
                    width = int(SETTINGS["wdh"]/self.width_chunks)
                    height = int(SETTINGS["hgt"]/self.height_chunks)
                    pos = [x*width, y*height]

                    self.draw_threads.append(Thread(target=draw_colored, args=(SETTINGS["oct"],
                                                                                  SETTINGS["scl"],
                                                                                  SETTINGS["sea"],
                                                                                  width,
                                                                                  height,
                                                                                  SETTINGS["lac"],
                                                                                  pos,
                                                                                  SETTINGS["seed"],
                                                                                  SETTINGS["noise"],
                                                                                  SETTINGS["offset"])))

            for p in self.draw_threads:
                p.start()

        def clear(self):
            self.map.fill((100, 100, 100))
            self.map_surface.fill(0)
            SHARED_MAP.clear()
            chunks_generated.value = 0

        def run(self):

            self.update()
            self.events()

        def reset_settings(self):
            self.oct_slider.set_mark(0)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_mark(60)
            self.scale_slider.set_mark(99)
            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(175)
            self.map.fill((100, 100, 100))
            self.width_slider.set_mark(50)
            self.height_slider.set_mark(50)
            self.lac_slider.set_mark(10)
            self.pos_entry.text = '0,0'
            self.seed_entry.text = '0'
            self.mmrect.topleft = self.map_rect.topleft
            self.movable_map_rect.topleft = (0, 0)
            self.dist = vec(0, 0)

        def update_settings(self):

            self.oct_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["oct"]-1)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["sea"])
            self.scale_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["scl"]-1)
            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["zoom_slider"])
            self.zoom = SETTINGS["zoom"]
            self.width_slider.set_mark(int((SETTINGS["wdh"]-100)/10))
            self.height_slider.set_mark(int((SETTINGS["hgt"]-100)/10))
            pos = SETTINGS["offset"]
            x = str(pos[0])
            y = str(pos[1])
            self.pos_entry.text = x+','+y
            self.lac_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["lac"]*10-10)
            self.seed_entry.text = str(SETTINGS["seed"])

        def update(self):
            mousepos = vec(pg.mouse.get_pos())
            p1 = pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
            # print(p1, mousepos)
            self.screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            if reset_settings.value:
                reset_settings.value = 0
                self.reset_settings()

            if apply_settings.value:
                apply_settings.value = 0
                self.update_settings()

            if generation_finished.value:
                generation_finished.value = 0

                width = len(SHARED_MAP.values()[0])
                height = len(SHARED_MAP.values()[0][0])

                self.map = pg.Surface((width*self.width_chunks, height*self.height_chunks))
                self.map.fill((100, 100, 100))
                self.map_surface.fill((100, 100, 100))

                for c in SHARED_MAP.items():
                    pos = c[0]
                    chunk = c[1]
                    map_chunk = pg.pixelcopy.make_surface(chunk)
                    self.map.blit(map_chunk, (pos[1], pos[0]))

                self.map = pg.transform.flip(pg.transform.rotate(self.map, -90), 1, 0)

            self.movable_map = pg.transform.scale(
                self.map, (int(SETTINGS["mwd"]*self.zoom), int(SETTINGS["mhg"]*self.zoom)))
            self.movable_map_rect.size = self.movable_map.get_rect().size
            self.mmrect = self.movable_map_rect.copy()
            self.mmrect.topleft = vec(self.mmrect.topleft) + vec(575, 25)

            if self.mmrect.collidepoint(mousepos) and self.map_rect.collidepoint(mousepos):
                mpos = vec(mousepos) - vec(575, 25)

                if p1 and not self.dragging:
                    self.dragging = True
                    self.dist = mousepos - vec(self.mmrect.topleft)

                elif self.dragging and p1:
                    self.mmrect.topleft = mousepos - self.dist
                    self.movable_map_rect.center = vec(self.mmrect.center) - vec(575, 25)
                elif self.dragging and not p1:
                    self.dragging = False

            self.map_surface.fill(0)
            self.map_surface.blit(self.movable_map, self.movable_map_rect)
            self.screen.blit(self.map_surface, self.map_rect)
            pg.draw.rect(self.screen, (0, 0, 0), self.map_rect, 1)
            for w in self.widgets:
                w.update()

            SETTINGS["oct"] = self.oct_slider.mark+1
            SETTINGS["scl"] = self.scale_slider.mark+1
            SETTINGS["sea"] = self.sea_level_slider.mark
            try:
                seed = int(self.seed_entry.text)
            except:
                if self.seed_entry.text.strip() != '':
                    seed = int("".join([str(ord(c)) for c in self.seed_entry.text]))
                else:
                    seed = 0

            self.oct_slider.set_label("Octaves: "+str(self.oct_slider.mark+1))
            self.sea_level_slider.set_label("Sea level: "+str(self.sea_level_slider.mark))
            self.scale_slider.set_label("Scale: "+str(self.scale_slider.mark+1))

            self.zoom_slider.set_label("Zoom: "+str(self.zoom_slider.max-self.zoom_slider.mark-25))
            SETTINGS["zoom_slider"] = self.zoom_slider.mark

            zoomval = (self.zoom_slider.max-self.zoom_slider.mark)/25
            if zoomval <= 0:
                self.zoom = 0.025
            else:
                self.zoom = zoomval

            SETTINGS["zoom"] = self.zoom

            self.width_slider.set_label("Width: "+str((self.width_slider.mark)*10+100))
            SETTINGS["wdh"] = (self.width_slider.mark)*10+100
            self.height_slider.set_label("Height: "+str((self.height_slider.mark)*10+100))
            SETTINGS["hgt"] = (self.height_slider.mark)*10+100

            self.lac_slider.set_label("Lacunarity: "+str((self.lac_slider.mark+10)/10))
            SETTINGS["lac"] = (self.lac_slider.mark+10)/10

            pos = self.pos_entry.text.strip().split(',')
            for i, p in enumerate(pos):
                if p != '':
                    try:
                        pos[i] = int(p)
                    except:
                        pos[i] = 0

            SETTINGS["offset"] = pos

            pg.display.flip()

        def events(self):
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    if not in_settings.value:
                        quit_settings.value = 1
                        raise SystemExit
                if event.type == pg.MOUSEWHEEL:
                    if self.map_rect.collidepoint(pg.mouse.get_pos()):
                        try:
                            m = self.zoom_slider.mark-event.y
                            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(m)
                        except:
                            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(200)

    e = Editor()
    while True:
        e.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    set = Process(target=sw)
    ed = Process(target=editor)
    set.start()
    ed.start()
    set.join()
    ed.join()
```

Here is the "settings.json" file needed to run the script:

```json
{
    "oct": 8,
    "scl": 300,
    "sea": 60,
    "lac": 2.3,
    "seed": 0,
    "wdh": 600,
    "hgt": 600,
    "offset": [100, 100],
    "mwd": 600,
    "mhg": 600,
    "zoom": 1.0,
    "zoom_slider": 175,
    "noise": 1
}
```

UPDATE: I have been able to find the line causing the error, which is line 12, `manager = Manager()`. I have tried looking for issues on the github repo, but I haven't been able to find anything. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: And this is an exe file you have created and if so, how did you create it?

Comment: @Booboo I have not made an executable, the file is still .py, and I haven't planned on compiling it.

Comment: The problem is tricky.  Remember that, with `multiprocessing`, every new process will load and run your file again, which means it re-runs all of the initialization.  That's why it's so absolutely critical that all of your one-time initialization happen in an `if __file__=="__main__"` section, and I suspect that includes creating the multiprocessing.Manager.

Comment: @TimRoberts I suspected something like that could be the problem, but I have tried moving parts of the code inside the `if __name__=="__main__"` section, but I can't find a way to get it working. I have tried putting it in a function as a global variable and calling the function in the `if __name__=="__main__"` section, moving everything, but every attempt gives me a brand new error

Comment: Well, then ask a brand new question.  ;)  You're on the right track.

Comment: @TimRoberts I might just give up then tbh I have been trying to fix this for way too long

Comment: You have a global variable `apply_settings`. Then in class `Screen` you have a method  named `apply_settings` in which you have the statement `apply_settings.value = 1`. But this is not modifying the global variable but rather adding an attribute to the method `apply_settings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have `pygame` installed and did not want to install it because I do not know `pygame` and am not really in a position to debug your program if you have other issues with your code other than the obvious things I saw. So I was not able to really test this. But I believe this is at least a good start in the right direction, if not perfect.

Instead of starting two processes, I have created a processing pool of size 2 to which I submit 2 "tasks." But what this allows me to do is to create the managed variables in my main process within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block and then to initialize *each* process in the pool with global variables initialized with these values using a special pool initializer function. The only other change I made is based on the comment I posted to your question. I have therefore renamed method `apply_settings` to `apply_our_settings`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import signal
import sys
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Value
from threading import Thread
import pygame as pg
import traceback

# initialize processing pool's processes with global variables:
def init_pool(settings, shared_map, s_s, i_s, q_s, r_s, g_f, g_s, c_g, a_s):
    global SETTINGS, SHARED_MAP, start_settings, in_settings, quit_settings, reset_settings, \
           generation_finished, generation_started, chunks_generated, apply_settings
    SETTINGS = settings
    SHARED_MAP = shared_map
    start_settings = s_s
    in_settings = i_s
    quit_settings = q_s
    reset_settings = r_s
    generation_finished = g_f
    generation_started = g_s
    chunks_generated = c_g
    apply_settings = a_s


def remap(OldValue, OldMin, OldMax, NewMin, NewMax):
    OldRange = (float(OldMax) - float(OldMin))
    NewRange = (float(NewMax) - float(NewMin))
    NewValue = (((float(OldValue) - float(OldMin)) * NewRange) / OldRange) + float(NewMin)
    return NewValue


def create_noise(iterations, x, y, scale, lacunarity, low, high, ngen):
    maxAmp = 0
    amp = 1
    persistence = 0.5
    freq = scale
    noise = 0

    for i in range(iterations):
        noise = noise + ngen.noise2d(x/freq, y/freq) * amp
        maxAmp = maxAmp + amp
        amp = amp * persistence
        freq = freq / lacunarity

    noise = noise / maxAmp

    noise = noise * (high - low) / 2 + (high + low) / 2

    return int(high-noise)


def draw_colored(octv, scale, sea, width, height, lac, pos, seed, noise, offset):

    from noise import pnoise2, snoise2
    from opensimplex import OpenSimplex
    import numpy as np

    generation_started.value = 1
    xoffset = offset[0] + pos[0]
    yoffset = offset[1] + pos[1]
    world = np.full((height, width, 3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
    normal_world = world.copy()
    # Color all pixels
    for x in range(width):
        # print(x)
        for y in range(height):
            if noise == 2:
                n = remap(snoise2((x+xoffset)/scale, (y+yoffset)/scale,
                                  octaves=octv, base=seed, lacunarity=lac), -1, 1, 0, 100)
            elif noise == 1:
                n = remap(pnoise2((x+xoffset)/scale, (y+yoffset)/scale,
                                  octaves=octv, base=seed, lacunarity=lac), -1, 1, 0, 100)
            elif noise == 0:
                ngen = OpenSimplex(seed)
                n = create_noise(octv, x+xoffset, y+yoffset, scale, lac, 0, 100, ngen)

            color_dist = int((100-sea)/(octv+2))

            if n >= sea:
                r = range(sea, 100, color_dist)
                hmap = []
                cmap = []
                for i in r:
                    hmap.append(i)
                    cmap.append(remap(i, sea, 100, 150, 255))

                d = 255-max(cmap)

                for i, h in enumerate(hmap):
                    if n >= h:
                        normal_world[y][x][0] = cmap[i]/6
                        normal_world[y][x][1] = cmap[i] + d
                        normal_world[y][x][2] = cmap[i]/2

                        world[y][x][0] = cmap[i]/2
                        world[y][x][1] = cmap[i]
                        world[y][x][2] = cmap[i]/3

            else:
                r = range(0, sea, color_dist*2+1)
                hmap = []
                cmap = []
                for i in r:
                    hmap.append(i)
                    cmap.append(remap(i, 0, sea, 50, 150))

                for i, h in enumerate(hmap):
                    if n >= h:
                        normal_world[y][x][0] = 0
                        normal_world[y][x][1] = 0
                        normal_world[y][x][2] = cmap[i]

                        world[y][x][0] = cmap[i]
                        world[y][x][1] = 0
                        world[y][x][2] = 0

    SHARED_MAP[tuple(pos)] = normal_world
    generation_started.value = 0
    generation_finished.value = 1
    chunks_generated.value += 1


def sw():

    import pygame as pg
    from pgui import Slider, Entry, Button, CheckBox
    import json
    import os

    pg.init()
    pg.display.set_caption("Settings")

    class CustomCheckBox:
        def __init__(self, parent, *, x=0, y=0, size=20):
            self.parent = parent
            self.screen = parent.screen
            self.box = CheckBox(self, x=x, y=y, size=size)

            self.bg_color = (255, 255, 255)
            self.border_width = 3
            self.border_color = (0, 0, 0)
            self.check_color = (0, 200, 0)
            self.cross_width = 5
            self.checked = False
            self.check_style = "fill"
            self.label_side = "top"
            self.label_align = "left"
            self.label_padding = 3

        def update(self):
            self.group = self.parent.noise_options
            if self.box.clicked:
                self.checked = True
                for c in self.group:
                    if c != self:
                        c.checked = False
            else:
                pass
            self.sync_attributes()
            self.box.update()

        def sync_attributes(self):
            # ------- ATTRIBUTES -------
            self.box.bg_color = self.bg_color
            self.box.border_width = self.border_width
            self.box.border_color = self.border_color
            self.box.check_color = self.check_color
            self.box.cross_width = self.cross_width
            self.box.checked = self.checked
            self.box.check_style = self.check_style
            self.box.label_side = self.label_side
            self.box.label_align = self.label_align
            self.box.label_padding = self.label_padding
            # --------------------------

        def move(self, x, y):
            self.box.move(x, y)

        def set_font(self, font):
            self.box.set_font(font)

        def set_font_size(self, size):
            self.box.set_font_size(size)

        def set_font_color(self, color):
            self.box.set_font_color(color)

        def set_size(self, size):
            self.box.set_size(size)

        def set_style(self, style):
            self.box.set_style(style)

        def set_label(self, text):
            self.box.set_label(text)

    class Screen:
        def create(self):

            self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))

            self.load_button = Button(self, text="Load config", func=self.load)
            self.load_button.move(20, 555)
            self.load_button.height = 25
            self.load_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.save_button = Button(self, text="Save config", func=self.save)
            self.save_button.move(145, 555)
            self.save_button.height = 25
            self.save_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.reset_button = Button(self, text="Reset config", func=self.reset)
            self.reset_button.move(270, 555)
            self.reset_button.height = 25
            self.reset_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.opensimplex_option = CustomCheckBox(self, x=20, y=20)
            self.opensimplex_option.check_color = (0, 0, 0)
            self.opensimplex_option.set_font_size(15)
            self.opensimplex_option.set_label("OpenSimplex noise")
            self.opensimplex_option.label_side = "right"
            self.opensimplex_option.label_padding = 5

            self.perlin_noise_option = CustomCheckBox(self, x=20, y=50)
            self.perlin_noise_option.check_color = (0, 0, 0)
            self.perlin_noise_option.set_font_size(15)
            self.perlin_noise_option.set_label("Perlin noise")
            self.perlin_noise_option.label_side = "right"
            self.perlin_noise_option.label_padding = 5

            self.simplex_option = CustomCheckBox(self, x=20, y=80)
            self.simplex_option.check_color = (0, 0, 0)
            self.simplex_option.set_font_size(15)
            self.simplex_option.set_label("Simplex noise")
            self.simplex_option.label_side = "right"
            self.simplex_option.label_padding = 5

            self.settings_file = Entry(self, x=20, y=500, border=1, size=15, width=300)
            self.settings_file.width = 300
            self.settings_file.text = "settings.json"
            self.settings_file.set_label("Settings file:")

            self.noise_options = [
                self.opensimplex_option,
                self.perlin_noise_option,
                self.simplex_option
            ]

            self.noise_options[SETTINGS["noise"]].checked = True

            self.widgets = [
                self.load_button,
                self.save_button,
                self.reset_button,
                self.opensimplex_option,
                self.perlin_noise_option,
                self.simplex_option,
                self.settings_file
            ]

            for w in self.widgets:
                w.border_width = 1

        def load(self):
            filename = self.settings_file.text
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                    settings = json.load(f)

                SETTINGS.update(settings)

                self.apply_our_settings()
                self.settings_file.set_label("Settings file:")
            else:
                self.settings_file.set_label("Settings file:    No file at " + os.path.abspath(filename))

        def save(self):
            settings = SETTINGS.copy()
            filename = "settings.json"
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(settings, f)

        def apply_our_settings(self):
            apply_settings.value = 1
            for i in self.noise_options:
                i.checked = False
            self.noise_options[SETTINGS["noise"]].checked = True

        def reset(self):
            reset_settings.value = 1
            SETTINGS["noise"] = 2
            self.noise_options[2].checked = True
            self.noise_options[0].checked = False
            self.noise_options[1].checked = False

        def run(self):
            if start_settings.value:
                self.create()
                start_settings.value = 0
                in_settings.value = 1
            if in_settings.value:
                self.update()
                self.events()
            if quit_settings.value:
                raise SystemExit

        def update(self):
            self.screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            for w in self.widgets:
                w.update()

            noises = [
                self.opensimplex_option.checked,
                self.perlin_noise_option.checked,
                self.simplex_option.checked
            ]

            for i, n in enumerate(noises):
                if noises[i]:
                    SETTINGS["noise"] = i

            pg.display.flip()

        def events(self):
            if in_settings.value:
                for event in pg.event.get():
                    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                        in_settings.value = 0
                        pg.display.quit()
                    elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                            in_settings.value = 0
                            pg.display.quit()

    sc = Screen()
    while True:
        sc.run()


def editor():
    import pygame as pg
    from pgui import Slider, Entry, Button, CheckBox
    import os
    import cv2

    pg.init()

    screen = pg.display.set_mode((1200, 704))
    pg.display.set_caption("Map creator")

    vec = pg.math.Vector2

    class Editor:
        def __init__(self):
            self.screen = screen
            self.value = 5

            self.oct_slider = Slider(self, max=7)
            self.oct_slider.move(20, 40)
            self.oct_slider.set_length(300)
            self.oct_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.oct_slider.set_width(15)
            self.oct_slider.set_label("Octaves: 1")
            self.oct_slider.set_mark(0)

            self.sea_level_slider = Slider(self)
            self.sea_level_slider.move(20, 80)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_length(300)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_width(15)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_label("Sea level: 60")
            self.sea_level_slider.set_mark(60)

            self.scale_slider = Slider(self, max=599)
            self.scale_slider.move(575, 660)
            self.scale_slider.set_length(585)
            self.scale_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.scale_slider.set_width(15)
            self.scale_slider.set_label("Scale: 100")
            self.scale_slider.set_mark(99)

            self.zoom_slider = Slider(self, max=200, orientation="vertical")
            self.zoom_slider.move(525, 25)
            self.zoom_slider.set_length(585)
            self.zoom_slider.label_align = "center"
            self.zoom_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.zoom_slider.set_label("Zoom: 1")
            self.zoom_slider.set_width(15)
            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(175)
            self.zoom = 1

            self.map_surface = pg.Surface((600, 600))
            self.map_surface.fill(0)
            self.map_rect = self.map_surface.get_rect()
            self.map_rect.topleft = (575, 25)
            self.map = pg.Surface((SETTINGS["wdh"], SETTINGS["hgt"]))
            self.map.fill((100, 100, 100))

            self.width_slider = Slider(self, max=120)
            self.width_slider.move(20, 120)
            self.width_slider.set_length(300)
            self.width_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.width_slider.set_width(15)
            self.width_slider.set_label("Width: 600")
            self.width_slider.set_mark(50)

            self.height_slider = Slider(self, max=120)
            self.height_slider.move(20, 160)
            self.height_slider.set_length(300)
            self.height_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.height_slider.set_width(15)
            self.height_slider.set_label("Height: 600")
            self.height_slider.set_mark(50)

            self.pos_entry = Entry(self, x=20, y=200, border=1, size=15)
            self.pos_entry.text = '0,0'
            self.pos_entry.set_label("X,Y Position:")

            self.lac_slider = Slider(self, max=40)
            self.lac_slider.move(20, 240)
            self.lac_slider.set_length(300)
            self.lac_slider.set_font_size(15)
            self.lac_slider.set_width(15)
            self.lac_slider.set_label("Lacunarity: 2")
            self.lac_slider.set_mark(10)

            self.seed_entry = Entry(self, x=20, y=360, border=1, size=15)
            self.seed_entry.text = '0'
            self.seed_entry.set_label("Seed:")

            self.draw_button = Button(self, x=20, y=625, text="Generate", func=self.draw)
            self.draw_button.width = 315

            self.clear_button = Button(self, x=345, y=625, text="Clear", func=self.clear)

            self.settings_button = Button(self, x=20, y=570, text='Settings', func=self.settings)
            self.settings_button.height = 25
            self.settings_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.abort_button = Button(self, x=140, y=570, text='Abort', func=self.abort_generation)
            self.abort_button.height = 25
            self.abort_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.save_button = Button(self, x=260, y=570, text='Save', func=self.save)
            self.save_button.height = 25
            self.save_button.set_font_size(15)

            self.save_name = Entry(self, x=380, y=570)
            self.save_name.text = "image.png"
            self.save_name.set_font_size(15)
            self.save_name.set_label("Save to file:")

            self.widgets = [
                self.oct_slider,
                self.sea_level_slider,
                self.draw_button,
                self.scale_slider,
                self.zoom_slider,
                self.width_slider,
                self.height_slider,
                self.pos_entry,
                self.lac_slider,
                self.seed_entry,
                self.clear_button,
                self.settings_button,
                self.abort_button,
                self.save_button,
                self.save_name
            ]

            self.width_chunks = 4
            self.height_chunks = 4

            for w in self.widgets:
                w.border_width = 1
                if isinstance(w, Slider):
                    w.pointer_border_width = 1

            self.movable_map_rect = pg.Rect((0, 0), (600, 600))
            self.dragging = False
            self.dist = vec(0, 0)

        def settings(self):
            start_settings.value = 1

        def save(self):
            filename = self.save_name.text
            if filename[-4:] != ".png":
                filename += ".png"
            surf = pg.transform.rotate(self.map, 90)
            surf = pg.transform.flip(surf, 0, 1)
            image = []
            for x in range(SETTINGS["mwd"]):
                row = []
                for y in range(SETTINGS["mhg"]):
                    row.append(surf.get_at((x, y)))
                image.append(row)
            image = np.array(image)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            print("saving image")
            cv2.imwrite(filename, image)

        def abort_generation(self):
            if generation_started.value:
                print("Generation aborted")
                for p in self.draw_threads:
                    p.terminate()
                    p.join()
                generation_started.value = 0

        def draw(self):
            SETTINGS["mwd"] = SETTINGS["wdh"]
            SETTINGS["mhg"] = SETTINGS["hgt"]

            SHARED_MAP.clear()
            chunks_generated.value = 0

            self.draw_threads = []

            for x in range(self.width_chunks):
                for y in range(self.height_chunks):
                    width = int(SETTINGS["wdh"]/self.width_chunks)
                    height = int(SETTINGS["hgt"]/self.height_chunks)
                    pos = [x*width, y*height]

                    self.draw_threads.append(Thread(target=draw_colored, args=(SETTINGS["oct"],
                                                                                  SETTINGS["scl"],
                                                                                  SETTINGS["sea"],
                                                                                  width,
                                                                                  height,
                                                                                  SETTINGS["lac"],
                                                                                  pos,
                                                                                  SETTINGS["seed"],
                                                                                  SETTINGS["noise"],
                                                                                  SETTINGS["offset"])))

            for p in self.draw_threads:
                p.start()

        def clear(self):
            self.map.fill((100, 100, 100))
            self.map_surface.fill(0)
            SHARED_MAP.clear()
            chunks_generated.value = 0

        def run(self):

            self.update()
            self.events()

        def reset_settings(self):
            self.oct_slider.set_mark(0)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_mark(60)
            self.scale_slider.set_mark(99)
            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(175)
            self.map.fill((100, 100, 100))
            self.width_slider.set_mark(50)
            self.height_slider.set_mark(50)
            self.lac_slider.set_mark(10)
            self.pos_entry.text = '0,0'
            self.seed_entry.text = '0'
            self.mmrect.topleft = self.map_rect.topleft
            self.movable_map_rect.topleft = (0, 0)
            self.dist = vec(0, 0)

        def update_settings(self):

            self.oct_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["oct"]-1)
            self.sea_level_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["sea"])
            self.scale_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["scl"]-1)
            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["zoom_slider"])
            self.zoom = SETTINGS["zoom"]
            self.width_slider.set_mark(int((SETTINGS["wdh"]-100)/10))
            self.height_slider.set_mark(int((SETTINGS["hgt"]-100)/10))
            pos = SETTINGS["offset"]
            x = str(pos[0])
            y = str(pos[1])
            self.pos_entry.text = x+','+y
            self.lac_slider.set_mark(SETTINGS["lac"]*10-10)
            self.seed_entry.text = str(SETTINGS["seed"])

        def update(self):
            mousepos = vec(pg.mouse.get_pos())
            p1 = pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
            # print(p1, mousepos)
            self.screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            if reset_settings.value:
                reset_settings.value = 0
                self.reset_settings()

            if apply_settings.value:
                apply_settings.value = 0
                self.update_settings()

            if generation_finished.value:
                generation_finished.value = 0

                width = len(SHARED_MAP.values()[0])
                height = len(SHARED_MAP.values()[0][0])

                self.map = pg.Surface((width*self.width_chunks, height*self.height_chunks))
                self.map.fill((100, 100, 100))
                self.map_surface.fill((100, 100, 100))

                for c in SHARED_MAP.items():
                    pos = c[0]
                    chunk = c[1]
                    map_chunk = pg.pixelcopy.make_surface(chunk)
                    self.map.blit(map_chunk, (pos[1], pos[0]))

                self.map = pg.transform.flip(pg.transform.rotate(self.map, -90), 1, 0)

            self.movable_map = pg.transform.scale(
                self.map, (int(SETTINGS["mwd"]*self.zoom), int(SETTINGS["mhg"]*self.zoom)))
            self.movable_map_rect.size = self.movable_map.get_rect().size
            self.mmrect = self.movable_map_rect.copy()
            self.mmrect.topleft = vec(self.mmrect.topleft) + vec(575, 25)

            if self.mmrect.collidepoint(mousepos) and self.map_rect.collidepoint(mousepos):
                mpos = vec(mousepos) - vec(575, 25)

                if p1 and not self.dragging:
                    self.dragging = True
                    self.dist = mousepos - vec(self.mmrect.topleft)

                elif self.dragging and p1:
                    self.mmrect.topleft = mousepos - self.dist
                    self.movable_map_rect.center = vec(self.mmrect.center) - vec(575, 25)
                elif self.dragging and not p1:
                    self.dragging = False

            self.map_surface.fill(0)
            self.map_surface.blit(self.movable_map, self.movable_map_rect)
            self.screen.blit(self.map_surface, self.map_rect)
            pg.draw.rect(self.screen, (0, 0, 0), self.map_rect, 1)
            for w in self.widgets:
                w.update()

            SETTINGS["oct"] = self.oct_slider.mark+1
            SETTINGS["scl"] = self.scale_slider.mark+1
            SETTINGS["sea"] = self.sea_level_slider.mark
            try:
                seed = int(self.seed_entry.text)
            except:
                if self.seed_entry.text.strip() != '':
                    seed = int("".join([str(ord(c)) for c in self.seed_entry.text]))
                else:
                    seed = 0

            self.oct_slider.set_label("Octaves: "+str(self.oct_slider.mark+1))
            self.sea_level_slider.set_label("Sea level: "+str(self.sea_level_slider.mark))
            self.scale_slider.set_label("Scale: "+str(self.scale_slider.mark+1))

            self.zoom_slider.set_label("Zoom: "+str(self.zoom_slider.max-self.zoom_slider.mark-25))
            SETTINGS["zoom_slider"] = self.zoom_slider.mark

            zoomval = (self.zoom_slider.max-self.zoom_slider.mark)/25
            if zoomval <= 0:
                self.zoom = 0.025
            else:
                self.zoom = zoomval

            SETTINGS["zoom"] = self.zoom

            self.width_slider.set_label("Width: "+str((self.width_slider.mark)*10+100))
            SETTINGS["wdh"] = (self.width_slider.mark)*10+100
            self.height_slider.set_label("Height: "+str((self.height_slider.mark)*10+100))
            SETTINGS["hgt"] = (self.height_slider.mark)*10+100

            self.lac_slider.set_label("Lacunarity: "+str((self.lac_slider.mark+10)/10))
            SETTINGS["lac"] = (self.lac_slider.mark+10)/10

            pos = self.pos_entry.text.strip().split(',')
            for i, p in enumerate(pos):
                if p != '':
                    try:
                        pos[i] = int(p)
                    except:
                        pos[i] = 0

            SETTINGS["offset"] = pos

            pg.display.flip()

        def events(self):
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    if not in_settings.value:
                        quit_settings.value = 1
                        raise SystemExit
                if event.type == pg.MOUSEWHEEL:
                    if self.map_rect.collidepoint(pg.mouse.get_pos()):
                        try:
                            m = self.zoom_slider.mark-event.y
                            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(m)
                        except:
                            self.zoom_slider.set_mark(200)

    e = Editor()
    while True:
        e.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()

    SETTINGS = manager.dict()

    start_settings = Value('i', 0)
    in_settings = Value('i', 0)
    quit_settings = Value('i', 0)
    reset_settings = Value('i', 0)
    generation_finished = Value('i', 0)
    generation_started = Value('i', 0)
    chunks_generated = Value('i', 0)
    apply_settings = Value('i', 0)


    SETTINGS["oct"] = 1
    SETTINGS["scl"] = 250
    SETTINGS["sea"] = 60
    SETTINGS["lac"] = 2
    SETTINGS["seed"] = 0
    SETTINGS["wdh"] = 600
    SETTINGS["hgt"] = 600
    SETTINGS["offset"] = [0, 0]
    SETTINGS["mwd"] = 600
    SETTINGS["mhg"] = 600
    SETTINGS["zoom"] = 0
    SETTINGS["zoom_slider"] = 0
    SETTINGS["noise"] = 2

    SHARED_MAP = manager.dict()

    # create pool with two processes and initialize global variables:
    pool = Pool(2, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(SETTINGS,
                                                    SHARED_MAP,
                                                    start_settings,
                                                    in_settings,
                                                    quit_settings,
                                                    reset_settings,
                                                    generation_finished,
                                                    generation_started,
                                                    chunks_generated,
                                                    apply_settings))
    result1 = pool.apply_async(sw)
    result2 = pool.apply_async(editor)
    # wait for tasks to complete:
    try:
        return_value_1 = result1.get()
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.print_exc())
    try:
        return_value_2 = result2.get()
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.print_exc())
```

Note: Since your tasks do not actually return any values of interest, I could have awaited for the tasks to complete by issuing the following two commands in lieu of calling `get()` on the `AsycnResult` instances returned by the calls to `apply_async`:

```py
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

But then any exceptions thrown in your tasks would not be detected.

I also question whether shared `Value` variables `start_settings` through `apply_settings` really needed to be implemented as `shared` variables; they don't seem to be shared with another process.

Comment: I can't believe you actually went through all my badly implemented, uncommented code and managed to fix it. Thank you very much for your help and support!
About the `start_settings` and `apply_settings` variables, I use them to send signals between both processes without having to find their PID. One process sets the value to 1, and when the other notices, it does whatever it needs to do, and sets it back to 0. `start_settings` is used to tell the settings window to open, while the `apply_settings` one is used to tell the editor to apply the settings loaded by the settings window process.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a terrible implementation and a bad idea, but that's what I came up to when I first wrote the code, and I am still learning the ways of multiprocessing, so I didn't know any better